# Updating Qt code from createTextureFromId to createTextureFromNativeObject

Tags: c++, qt

I have a piece of Code looking like this:

```cpp
// Before the scene graph starts to render, we update to the pending texture
    void prepareNode()
    {
        m_Lock.lock();
        int newId = m_ID;
        QSize size = m_Size;
        m_ID = 0;
        m_Lock.unlock();

        if (newId)
        {
            delete m_Texture;
            // note: include QQuickWindow::TextureHasAlphaChannel if the rendered content
            // has alpha.
            m_Texture = m_Window->createTextureFromId(newId, size);
            setTexture(m_Texture);

            markDirty(DirtyMaterial);

            // This will notify the rendering thread that the texture is now being rendered
            // and it can start rendering to the other one.
            Q_EMIT textureInUse();
        }
    }
```

Now with updating Qt to 5.15, the function createTextureFromId is no longer supported and should be replaced with createTextureFromNativeObject.

However I was not able to find any helpful documentation on Qt side on how to get a QTNativeObject from a texture Id.
(My understanding of Qt is below basic)

Note:
Changing the layout and parent functions is a big overhead. The function is called like

```cpp
connect(m_QMLWindow->m_RenderThread, &QMLRenderThread::textureReady, node, &TextureNode::newTexture,
                Qt::DirectConnection);
```

I suppose there should be an easy way to traverse to createTextureFromNativeObject?

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue porting to Qt6.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
QQuickWindow::CreateTextureOptions texOpts;
if (hasAlphaChannel)
    texOpts.setFlag(QQuickWindow::TextureHasAlphaChannel);
    
m_Texture = m_Window->createTextureFromNativeObject(QQuickWindow::NativeObjectTexture, &newId, 0, size, texOpts);
```